# How to send upload files using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to upload files with ajax.

I have tried dropzone and ajaxupload, but both libraries are not working.

So I tried to do it on my own. Here is my input type file code:

```
<input id="le_images" class="form-control" type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
```

and here is my jQuery code

```
$('#le_images').change(function(){
  var file_data = $(this).prop("files");
        $.ajax({
            url:"upload.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                'file' : file_data
            },
            success:function(results){ 

            }
        });
});
```

Now I am sending this files on `upload.php` with above code. But I did not receive this. Can you tell me where am I wrong?

So can you guys suggest me how to do this?

Comment: use form data for image upload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

For image update use Formupload

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[2]);
```

and you can move the uploaded image to your folder and you can see the image there

in php

```
$logoval=$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                $target_file = "../".basename($logoval);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$target_file);
```

Comment: i dont have form element still i can use it??

Comment: If you dont have form you canot use this type

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have form element so here you go:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#fileUpload", function() {
  var file_data = $("#le_images").prop("files")[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("file", file_data)

  $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    dataType: 'script',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post'
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
});
</script>

<input id="le_images" type="file" name="le_images" />
<button id="fileUpload" value="Upload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use VanillaJS framework and AJAX technique to solve this problem. Also, consider that VanillaJS is fully implemented in browsers and you don't need to download additional files for your project

Lets dive into code, where I will show you simple example:

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="images[]" onclick='uploadMyFiles(); return false;' multiple>
```

**VanillaJS**

```
function uploadMyFiles()
{
    var formElement = document.querySelector(".form-control");
    var formData = new FormData();
    for(var i = 0; i < formElement.files.length; i++)
        formData.append("File"+i, formElement.files[i]);
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                var responseText = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "--Your URL goes here");
        xmlHttp.send(formData);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
$('#le_images').change(function(){
  var file_data = $(this).prop("files");
        $.ajax({
            url:"upload.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: formData,
            success:function(results){ 

            }
        });
});
```

A Simple example is given at [Upload multiple images using jQuery, Ajax and PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-using-jquery-ajax-php/)

Comment: i dont have form element still i can use it??